# Why my program exit after I enter the key

Tags: java

I am confused about this problem, cannot understand why the program always exited after I enter the first data. How to enter the String data?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Caesar {

    public static String encode(String enc, int offset) {
        offset = offset % 26 + 26;
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        for (char i : enc.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + offset) % 26 ));
                } else {
                    encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + offset) % 26 ));
                }
            } else {
                encoded.append(i);
            }
        }
        return encoded.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter key: ");
        int key = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter line: ");
        String str = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println( Cipher.encode( str, key ));

    }
}
```

Comment: @Jens readLine -> nextLine

Comment: @ScaryWombat  Yes you are right sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you enter the `Key` you also push the `<ENTER>` key.  This char needs to be consumed before continuing, so try

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter key: ");
    int key = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter line: ");
    String str = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println( Cipher.encode( str, key ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter key: ");
        int key = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter line: ");
        if (in.hasNext()) {
            String str = in.nextLine();
        }
```

or you can get input in a `while`